# Fiddler and ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, proxy, telerik, fiddler, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fiddle http requests from ChromeDriver and I configured proxy for it:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = "localhost:8888" };
return new ChromeDriver(path, options);
```

Proxy works, driver uses it, but I see nothing in Fiddler. I don't use any filters at all.

```
Fiddler v4.6.2.2
ChromeDriver v2.24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`options.Proxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = "ipv4.fiddler:8888" };`